# Why is the word Shofar somtimes spelled with a Vav and somtimes without a Vav?

Tags: words, rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, spelling-variants

There are times that the word Shofar is spelled without a Vav - for example

שמות: יט. טז.
ויהי ביום השלישי בהית הבקר ויהי קלת וברקים וענן כבד על ההר וקל **שפר** חזק מאד ויחרד כל העם אשר במחנה

or שמות: יט. יט.
ויהי קול **השפר** הולך וחזק מאד משה ידבר והאלהים יעננו בקול

and there are times it is spelled with a Vav - for example

ויקרא: כה. ט.
והעברת **שופר** תרועה בחדש השבעי בעשור לחדש ביום הכפרים תעבירו **שופר** בכל ארצכם

or יהושע: ו. ה.
והיה במשך בקרן היובל בשמעכם את קול **השופר** יריעו כל העם תרועה גדולה ונפלה חומת העיר תחתיה ועלו העם איש נגדו

Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure every word spelled with a cholam is often spelled without it as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Zohar, 10:304](http://www2.kabbalah.com/k/index.php/p=zohar/zohar&vol=19&sec=668):

> Rabbi Yehuda said: In "the sound of the Shofar," the word "Shofar" is spelled without the letter vav, for it has the same meaning as in the verse, "It pleased (Heb. shafar) Daryavesh" (Daniel 6:1) and in the verse, "O king, let my counsel be acceptable (Heb. yishpar) to you" (Daniel 4:24) and the verse, "I thought it good (Heb. shefar) to report the signs and wonders" (Daniel 3:32) - Meaning that these are expressions which speak of glory and beauty, which alludes to [Zeir Anpin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeir_Anpin), [the secret](http://www2.kabbalah.com/k/index.php/p=zohar/zohar&vol=5&sec=190) of [Tiferet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiphereth) (beauty).